# Jquery- offsetLeft doesn't work on scroll to right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to refresh left position on scroll by left/right arrow(on keybord) or middle mouse button.
Now left position is working only when i'm scrolling on down/up.

my script is simple:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if(scroll >= 672) {
  $('.firm-row-th').addClass("stickyHeader");
}else {
  $('.firm-row-th').removeClass("stickyHeader");
}

if($('.stickyHeader')[0]) {
  $('.stickyHeader').css({ 'left': -$('.firm-container').scrollLeft() + "px" });
}
});
```

My css:

```
.firm-container {
margin-left: 0px;
width: calc(100% - 8px);
white-space: nowrap;
border: 1px solid #222;
overflow-x: auto;
z-index: 10;
position: absolute;
background-color: #fff;
}
.firm-row {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
}
.firm-row-th {
display: table;
table-layout: fixed;
}

.stickyHeader {
position: fixed;
top:0;
}
```

I am adding [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/j4v90rw4/1/) ex.

Just try to scroll on right when `stickyheader` is on. You will see the `stickyHeader` is not refreshed. Then try to scroll down- `stickyheader` will refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are only listening to the scroll-event on the window, which scrolls up-don, but not on the .firm-container which scrolls left-right.

Update your JS like this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    handleScroll();
});

$('.firm-container').scroll(function() {
    handleScroll();
});

function handleScroll() {
var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

    if(scroll >= 2) {
    $('.firm-row-th').addClass("stickyHeader");//.css({ 'left': -$('.firmy-container').scrollLeft() + "px" });
    }else {
    $('.firm-row-th').removeClass("stickyHeader");
    }

    if($('.stickyHeader')[0])
    {
    $('.stickyHeader').css({ 'left': -$('.firm-container').scrollLeft() + "px" });
    }
}
```

js-fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/j4v90rw4/2/

Comment: Oh... so simple. Thanks :)